# Linear transformation and standard matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question:

**Let f be a linear transformation from $P_2$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ whose standard matrix is**

**A=$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$**

**a) evaluate $f(1+2x+x^2)$**

My answer: = (0,3,4)

**b) Find the matrix of $f$ with respect to the bases $B_1={(1+x,1-x+x^2,1)}$ of $P_2$ and $B_2=((1,1,1),(0,1,1),(1,0,1))$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$.**

Is this correct:

$f(1+x)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$
$f(1-x+x^2)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
$f(1)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Which gives me transition matrix:
$P_{B_1>P_2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Then I have transition matrix: 
$P_{B_2>\mathbb{R^3}}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Solving for

$[f]_{B_2,B_1}=(P_{B_2>\mathbb{R^3}})^-1 A P_{B_1>P_2}$
$=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$[f]_{B_2,B_1}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You need to specify a basis for $P_2$; there are two natural orders $\{1,x,x^2\}$ and $\{x^2,x,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is my answer correct?